# How do I refresh results on my site with AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

How do I refresh results on my site with AJAX?

```
<div id="Results">
    // Mysql info to show a list of <li>
</div>
```

I want to refresh the div every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your AJAX code inside the [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) javascript function

```
setInterval("getListItems()", 600000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) element with a recursive function.

example (I didn't test):

```
function reload(url,miliseconds) {        
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#container').text('');
        $('#containter').load(url);
         return reload(url,miliseconds);
    },miliseconds);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    reload('http://www.website.com/dynamic_content.php',600000);
});
```

Comment: Explain the benefit of this, when it can be achieved with 1 line of code?

Comment: You mentioned putting his own AJAX code, you titled it with "getListItems()". is this a core function ? I don't think so, unlike you, I also coded that for him as "reload()". Apart from that, both our examples are triggered with one single line of code.

Comment: You're rewriting a core function for what purpose? What if he needs to massage the data coming from MySQL, what if the PHP page outputs JSON?